# Navigation from Container view to full screen - Swift 4

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, swift4

I have a `TableView` in a Container in my app which takes half screen. I embed it into `NavigationController` because I want to show detail screen on item click. I am going to detail screen with "show" segue. when I click on `tableView` row it goes to detail screen but detail screen is being shown inside that container (half screen). It should take full screen space. what is the problem?

Comment: Do you want the "detail screen" to be presented as a modal view *over* your "main view"? Or, is your "main view" part of a `UINavigationController` and you want to ***push*** the detail view?

Comment: In my case the `UINavigationController` is nested inside a container which shows a 'UITableView'. When I click on row I want that detail to be shown over the full screen and not in the container.